# Crazyhouse Chess: Playing with a real board and overall popularity?

Tags: chess-variants, bughouse, crazyhouse

Played a decent amount of bughouse but only started with crazyhouse a month or less ago. Although on the surface very similar games, I would say they are fundamentally different because there is no partner and so crazyhouse is "deterministic." I think that bughouse must be more popular if only because all that is required to play are two boards and two standard sets whereas crazyhouse is much better suited to online (I guess you could have bicolored pieces to play live.) So is crazyhouse catching on at all? Has anyone seen a set that would allow playing live? (I note there is not yet a tag for crazyhouse.)

Comment: Haha I would think bughouse chess is more skill and coordination reliant.  Crazy house is really just planning forward to get the pieces you need for a win

Comment: @QuIcKmAtHs: Bughouse has a lot of skill but also, at least if both players on a team are not extremely good and coordinate well, a lot of luck. I would say that cz requires as much skill as standard chess plus is far less understood. probably engines are unbeatable but in bughouse, not yet i don't think, at least not with human+engine team.

Comment: Actually there's quite a lot of crazyhouse questions here. I've created a tag and attached it to some of them

Answer (score 3):

Very boring answer: when I was at the university, we used to play it on a real board with two sets of pieces. Whenever you take a piece, you exchange it with one of the correct color.

Comment: Interesting, kind of hard to not make mistakes I guess but it would work. Also, maybe pieces that could be flipped, just tiles with images of pieces.